# Each new member from the second divides the sum of all previous

Tags: number-theory

All integers from $1$ to $13$ are recorded in a sequence such that each number (from the second onwards) divides the sum of all previous numbers.

*What numbers can be in the third place and why?*

I know that any number from 1 to 13 can be in the third place but I don't know how to prove it.

$12,2, *1* ,5,10,3,11,4,8,7,9,6,13$

$11,1, *2* ,7,3,8,4,9,5,10,12,6,13$

$11,1, *3* ,5,10,2,4,12,8,7,9,6,13$

$9,3, *4* ,8,2,13,1,10,5,11,6,12,7$

$4,1, *5* ,10,2,11,3,12,8,7,9,6,13$

$11,1, *6* ,9,3,10,8,4,13,5,2,12,7$

$12,2, *7* ,1,11,3,9,5,10,4,8,6,13$

$7,1, *8* ,2,9,3,10,4,11,5,12,6,13$

$12,6, *9* ,3,10,8,4,13,5,7,11,2,1$

$9,1, *10* ,2,11,3,4,8,12,5,13,6,7$

$10,1, *11* ,2,3,9,4,8,12,5,13,6,7$

$10,2, *12* ,1,5,3,11,4,8,7,9,6,13$

$12,1, *13* ,2,4,8,10,5,11,6,9,3,7$

Comment: Assuming your arithmetic is correct, what you have written above is a proof. What more do you want?

Comment: I have exactly the same problems only with numbers from 1 to 37 and from 1 to 61.

Comment: You should edit the question to reflect this. As stated, there is nothing to say other than what Gerry already did.